# copying django admin in my project

Tags: django, django-admin, admin

i want to edit django admin.
i need somethings more than that but i only want to manipulate django admin so if i 
copy admin folder from this path C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib in my project and change this line in setting.py 
    'django.contrib.admin',
to this :
'admin'
now i can make any changes that i want.
i can change templates and views and ...
but if i do this have i done a right thing?
is that clear programing way or i should find a better way for doing that?
why i don't have to do this?
what's wrong with this solution?

Comment: I have almost the same question and even with bounty nobody can provide a good example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921378/enable-django-admin-functionality-at-frontend-with-inlines

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to completely change the admin views? It's possible to [extend admin views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) (add your own admin views, additional URL patterns, etc).

As for the templates, you could either copy the (entirely or just with some specific files) templates directory to your main project templates directory (directory name should remain "admin") if you want to change templates OR use custom templates for specific admin classes as mentioned in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options).

Otherwise, if you think you still need to copy entire admin module, be specific on what are you planning to achieve.

Comment: you are right i can copy templates to my my main project templates but i'm asking what am i losing if i do this?

Comment: I need to know what are you trying to achieve first, as said in the answer. Only then I can tell you what might be the best (IMHO) solution.